# display value on bar with d3js

Tags: d3.js

i want to show the values on the bar! with this code, it shows the value, but the values are moved...

Screenshot:
http://www.imgbox.de/users/public/images/DbD1jLKgnR.png

I want the values over or in the bar!

```
var state2 = chart2.selectAll(".state")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",0)"; });

state2.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
  .filter(function(d) { return d.name !== ""; }).call(d3.helper.tooltip()

            .attr({class: 'tooltip2'})
            .text(function(d, i){ return d.name + ': '+ (-((d.y0) - (d.y1))) ; })
        );

state2.selectAll("text.rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name) + x.rangeBand()/2; })
  .filter(function(d) { return d.name !== ""; }).filter(function(d) { return ((d.y0) - (d.y1))     !== 0; }).attr("y", function(d) { return (-((d.y0) - (d.y1))*8); })
  .filter(function(d) { return d.name !== ""; }) .filter(function(d) { return ((d.y0) - (d.y1)) !== 0; }).text(function(d) { return (-((d.y0) - (d.y1))); });
```

Comment: Try setting `text-anchor` to `middle` and `x` to `x.rangeBand()/2`. You'll also need to set `y` accordingly.

Comment: x is already to x.rangeband()/2? or how did you mean?

Comment: No, you're setting it to `x(d.name) + x.rangeBand()/2`.

Comment: How did you meant set y accordingly?

Comment: To the `y` position of the bar with a small offset, e.g. `y(d.y1) - 10`.